# CarrierWave - delete version only, not original

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is it possible to ONLY delete versions and keep the original file?

#### Uploading an image creates the original file and the :product_thumb version (Works).

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog # Amazon S3

  version :product_thumb, if: :create_thumb? do
      process :resize_to_fit => [15, 15]
  end

  protected


  def create_thumb?
      model.make_thumbnail 
  end

end
```

When i run:

```
prod = Product.first
prod.remove_image!
prod.save
```

Both the original and :product_thumb get deleted. But i only want to delete the version :product_thumb. I looked through the API and didn't see anything that would help.

#### I've been trying to get this to work in the console.

```
prod.remove_product_thumb_image!   --> # NoMethodError: undefined method
prod.remove_image(:product_thumb)  --> # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1for0)

# one idea was to get the file path of the version and delete it manually
prod.image.url(:product_thumb)    --> # path/to/file/product_thumb_test.png
```

#### Is there a way to delete the version through CarrierWave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all versions use:

```
prod.image.remove_versions!
```

To delete a specific version use:

```
prod.image.versions[:product_thumb].remove!
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I could find out, there's no short command to delete an image version. However, you can build a little Ruby script that will do it for you, i.e. delete the respective files.

#### Step 1: Remove the image files

Use a script like this:

```
Product.all.each do |p|
  path = File.delete(p.image.product_thumb.current_path)
  File.delete(path) if File.exists?(path.to_s)
end
```

#### Step 2: Remove the image version

Remove the `product_thumb` version from your ImageUploader.

#### Done!

It will be like there had never been an image version.